# Send custom property with value as JSON array

Tags: json, azure-application-insights

We want to send some events to Application Insights with data showing which features a user owns, and are available for the session. These are variable, and the list of items will probably grow/change as we continue deploying updates. Currently we do this by building a list of properties dynamically at start-up, with values of Available/True.

Since AI fromats each event data as JSON, we thought it would be interesting to send through custom data as JSON so it can be processed in a similar fashion. Having tried to send data as JSON though, we bumped into an issue where AI seems to send through escape characters in the strings: 
Eg. if we send a property through with JSON like:

```
{"Property":[{"Value1"},..]}
```

It gets saved in AI as:

```
{\"Property\":[{\"Value1\"},..]} ).
```

Has anyone successfully sent custom JSON to AI, or is the platform specifically trying to safeguard against such usage? In our case, where we parse the data out in Power BI, it would simplify and speed up a lot some queries by being able to send a JSON array.

Answer (score 1):

AI treats custom properties as strings, you'd have to stringify any json you want to send (and keep it under the length limit for custom property sizes), and then re-parse it on the other side.